# How to prevent object=constructor(); assignment in c++

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying to do:

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){/*need to initialize something here*/}
};

int main(){
    A a;      //OK
    a=A();    //not OK
    a=A(b);  //not OK
    ///Only A a; needs to be allowed.
    return 0;
}
```

I need to initialize something while preventing object initialization with copy constructor and also prevent assignment to existing object.

Note: It would be good if I can do this without `>=C++11`.

Comment: What about `A a; A b; a = b;`?

Comment: @immibis : that needs to be prevented too. Only `A a;` allowed

Comment: `a=A(B&);` that isn't a thing.

Comment: @VincentSavard It would be good if I don't have to use `>=C++11`

Comment: @Jahid: That's something quite important you shouldn't leave out of your question. You should definitely edit it into your question.

Comment: @Jahid No. It won't be, ever.

Comment: `a=A(A&);` that isn't a thing either.

Comment: "preventing object initialization with assignment" -- apples and oranges. **Initialization** is part of creating an object. **Assignment** is done to an existing object.

Comment: @PeteBecker : How about : `A a=A();` initialization and creation are done both at the same time.

Comment: @Jahid - that's initialization. It's not assignment, even though there's an `=` in it. It uses the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by declaring the assignment operator and the copy constructor in the private part, and not defining them.

For example:

```
class A {
private:
    A(A&); // declared, not defined

    void operator= (A&); // declared, not defined

public:
    A() { //do regular stuff }
}
```

However, if you are using C++11/C++14, you can use the `delete` keyword for more explicit case of this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { //do regular stuff }
    A(A&) = delete;

    void operator= (A&) = delete;
}
```

Since the move constructor and the move assignment operators will not be generated if you declare any of the destructor / copy constructor / assignment operator, you don't need to the same thing for them.

Answer (score 8):

Since C++11, just delete assignment operator:

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){/*need to initialize something here*/}
    A& operator =(const A&) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just `= delete;` the copy assignment operator:

```
class A {
    // ...
    void operator=(A) = delete;
};
```

Alternatively, if you don't use C++11 you can make the copy assignment private.

Comment: Any reason to use *strange* signature `void operator=(A)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 May be because it's shorter? It makes no difference with `(const A&)`, because `operator=` anyway will be deleted.

Comment: @vladon: But `A&` is shorter than `void`, and parameter `a` can be removed... so that reason, even if possible, has some contradictions...

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, didn't mention `void`. Really strange :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, the parameter should have been omitted (I'll delete it from the answer). The return type `void` tends to be short than the name of a "real" class which is often much longer than just one character. The use of a value parameter is primarily targeted at making it clear that the assignment operator doesn't have the requirement to take its parameter by reference as the copy constructor (obviously) has.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the assignment operator as deleted. For example

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){/*need to initialize something here*/}
    A & operator =( const A & ) = delete;
};
```

Or you can declare it `private`.

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){/*need to initialize something here*/}
    private:
    A & operator =( const A & );
};
```